# Xamarin iOS Icon Setup

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

"I'm trying to set the icon for the iOS application I developed with Xamarin Forms on my Windows device, but I can't seem to do it. I've tried everything suggested, but it's not working. Do I need to have a Mac device to set the icon? And if so, how can I do that?"

[Assets content here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gw73.png)
[info.plist content here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzhAx.png)

Comment: You can try to replace the picture of the `iPhone App` in the AppIcon in the `Assets.xcassets` file of the xamarin.ios project with your images of appropriate size. For specific operation steps, you can refer to [Application Icons in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons?tabs=windows#managing-icons-with-asset-catalogs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the screenshot you provided, you may be setting the [Alternate App Icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/alternate-app-icons#adding-alternate-icons-to-a-xamarinios-project).

if you want to replace the default Xamarin icon in your Xamarin.iOS project, you just need to replace the picture of the `iPhone App` in the AppIcon in the `Assets.xcassets` file of the Xamarin.iOS project with other images of appropriate size (2x scale needs 120×120 pixel, 3x scale needs 180×180 pixel).

For specific operation steps, you can refer to [Application Icons in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons?tabs=windows#managing-icons-with-asset-catalogs)

Comment: Thank you for guiding me through solving the problem.